# How can I convert all italic text to *italic* in libreoffice writer or something similar?

Tags: text-formatting, libreoffice-writer, discord

I want to copypaste text from discord while preserving formatting. It works if I copypaste text from discord browser version to libreoffice writer, and it looks fine there. But to copypaste it back in discord, I need to convert all *italic* text into *italic* text first.

There are probably online sites for this too, I'm not sure how to search for those though.

Comment: There is no automatic solution, you will have to manually add the asterisks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Edit > Find and Replace*. Under *Other options*, tick *Regular expressions*. Then click *Format* and specify *Style* as *Italic* for "Western" i.e. Standard font types. Press OK.

Now it should say "Italic" under the *Find* box. In that box, enter `.*` to search for everything.

In the *Replace* box, enter `*$0*` where $0 indicates the matched text. Finally, press *Replace All*.

[image: find and replace dialog]

If you plan to do this regularly, it might be better to write a macro to run when a hotkey or toolbar button is pressed.

Comment: I had to also click "Including Styles" for this to work for me. Also thanks!